# Ajax call to retrieve data of database by php of all customers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making a call to php file, which is picking up data of 'name' and 'email' row-by-row and need to send it as a ajax response to my index.html file. I can fetch the row data but unable to know, how to send back the data as a reply to ajax request in json form.

PHP Code:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0){

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "jname".$row["name"]."jemail".$row["email"];
    }

} 
else{
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: my personal opinion ... Title of this q is not good...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of just echoing out the data as you are, store it in an array and use `json_encode` to return it as a json string.

```
$return = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    $return['result'] = $result->num_rows.' results';
    $return['rows'] = array();
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $return['rows'][] = array(
                'jname' => $row['name'],
                'jemail' => $row['email']
            );
    }

} 
else{
    $return['result'] = "0 results";
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your result in array, and print it via json_encode()

```
$response = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0){

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $response[] = array( 
            'jname' => $row['name'],
            'jemail' => $row['email']
         );
    }

} 
echo json_encode($response);
exit();
```